# Clause explaining "the requirement that..."

Tags: verb-agreement, subjunctive-mood, clauses

What should the verb form in that clause be?

Example: which of the following is correct?

They need to obey the requirement that their pockets are empty.

or

They need to obey the requirement that their pockets be empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. They need to obey the ***requirement*** [that their pockets ***are*** empty].
> 2. They need to obey the ***requirement*** [that their pockets ***be*** empty].

Both versions are grammatical and mean the same thing.

Both versions involve **mandative** constructions: the mandative word *"requirement"*, and a mandative clause *"that their pockets are/be empty"*.

- Your first version (#1) is a **covert mandative**, due to having an ordinary declarative clause as its mandative clause (*"that their pockets* ***are*** *empty"*).
- Your second version (#2) is a **subjunctive mandative**, due to having a subjunctive clause as its mandative clause (*"that their pockets* ***be*** *empty"*).

For related info, there's the 2002 reference grammar by Huddleston and Pullum et al., *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (CGEL), pages 993-1002.

Comment: The second sentence is an example of [the present subjunctive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive) used in conjunction with the [declarative that-clause](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declarative_content_clause). I don't get why the first example is also considered to be correct here.

Comment: @[F.E.](http://english.stackexchange.com/users/57102/f-e) [It all makes sense now](http://books.google.com/books?id=AMAgAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA177&lpg=PA177&dq=covert+mandative&source=bl&ots=mLyT4giVZC&sig=ewTaKT9OLvDSXanBP9Ylto8M8nw&hl=en&sa=X&ei=_syOU8nvIOrksAS22oGwBw&ved=0CDQQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=covert%20mandative&f=false). I was conflating the two and failing to make the distinction. Good answer